# Using jQuery accordion from an external JS file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, accordion

I have a standard [jQuery accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/) which works fine. I want to reuse this in a lot of HTML files and it would be cleaner to have the JS in a file rather than have to repeat in a script tag in each HTML file.

My HTML header is:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

    <script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
```

My test.js file is:

```
$(function() {
  $("#accordion").accordion({
    heightStyle: "content",
    header: "h4"
  })
});
```

The accordion does not work for me when moved to test.js. When I try it in a [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/accordion-1w866o) I get: '$' is not defined.

I know $ is a shortcut for document.getElementById(). It was suggested to wrap the JS inside an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-immediately-invoked-function-expression-iife/) where the IIFE takes jQuery as an argument and assigns it to $ within its scope, ensuring that $ is defined:

```
(function($) { 
    $(function() { 
        $("#accordion").accordion({ 
            heightStyle: "content", 
            header: "h4" 
            }); 
    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

However, trying this in the [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/accordion-1w866o) leads to a jQuery not defined error. I have jQuery included before test.js as shown above so I am unsure why I am getting this error?

So, I am wondering how to get past this error and get the jQuery accordion working when the code is in a javascript file?

Incidentally, it seems like every HTML file that uses the accordion will need jQuery and jQuery-ui included as well as test.js. It seems like there is no way to move the jQuery files to be in test.js only.

Comment: $ is an alias for jQuery. It is practically the same as document.querySelectorAll(). It is a global variable. An IIFE is not required. You are missing the $(document).ready() wrapper. It is unclear from your question why $ is undefined, unless you cannot access the CDN it's being loaded from. And yes, if you have separate HTML pages, you will need to include all script tags in each of them.

Comment: @J.Titus - There are many differences between `$`/`jQuery` and `querySelectorAll`. An IIFE is useful when `$` may be overwritten. The `ready` wrapper is not missing, the OP has used the `$()` alias for it (I said there were many differences) inside the IIFE.

Comment: I tried src="module" for the javascript file and now the accordion is working but I don't understand as the javascript file still gives the jQuery error and the same fix does not work on my webpage...

I tried the $( document ).ready(function()  wrapper and now I have the first error back:  '$' is not defined.

I did not realise the [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/accordion-1w866o) was not publically accessible, that's fixed now and it shows the latest attempt after @J. Titus suggestion.

Comment: `type="module"` makes precisely no difference (since the module neither declares any top level variables nor makes use of `import`). It runs, without error, whether the `type` attribute is there or not. I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! click on [test.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/accordion-1w866o?file=/test.js) and see the console to the right it shows the error.

Comment: Your accordion is working with the original code. The errors are coming from [eslint](https://eslint.org/) because it doesn't like the usage of global variables. Add `/* globals $ */` to the top of your JS file and the errors disappear. You're also missing the CSS for jQuery UI, so it doesn't look like an accordion.

Comment: Thanks! I added jquery-ui.css, though I don't see a change. 
Adding /* globals $ */ caused another error actually, back to not recognising $. See [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/accordion-1w866o?file=/test.js)

Comment: It should be `/* globals jQuery */` because that's the name of the global variable you are accessing.

Comment: Quentin, yes!! The $/jQuery issue was not manifesting in the playground, but that change worked on my project, thanks! @Quentin Add an answer for that and I will accept it.